# is there about TransactionalEventListener always reveice event

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I want to use `@TransactionalEventListener` to receive after rollback event, but `@TransactionalEventListener` seem can receive everything event whatever in the transactional method.

**listener:**

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
public class TransactionListener {

    @TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_ROLLBACK,classes = TransactionEvent.class)
    public void onEventHandler(TransactionEvent event) {
        log.info("after rollback. event = {}", event);
    }

}
```

**test:**

```java
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Slf4j
public class TaskAutoRepoTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @Test
    public void saveTest() throws InterruptedException {

        publisher.publishEvent(new TransactionEvent("name", "sssssss"));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

when running test `TransactionListener` always receives event and print log.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pasting code in text, please consider sharing an actual sample that others can run. If you have a GitHub account, it is very easy to create a repo and copy/paste that stuff in a small project created from start.spring.io.

I've done that and it works as expected, see https://github.com/snicoll-scratches/test-so-58552671

Note that I kept the `Thread.sleep` part but you shouldn't be doing that if the transaction has been started outside of the boundary of that method as the sleep will prevent the transaction to complete.

Anyway, that code above doesn't match what you claim so something else must be going on. You can look at the sample project and send a PR to it with your change if you can still reproduce that issue.

EDIT: Thank you for providing a PR to my original sample. Your setup does not use transaction management at all (there is no transaction support, no transaction manager active). `TransactionalEventListener` is an `EventListener` so the event will be passed as is. I've added `@EnableTransactionManagement` to your PR and with the transaction infrastructure in place, things are working as expected.

Comment: Please check the pull request: https://github.com/snicoll-scratches/test-so-58552671/pull/1

Comment: Thank you very much. There are working as expected when adding @EnableTransactionManagement to the app.